# How much time does it take for a shop to restock caps?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I admit that I'm used to Fallout 3, where stores restocked twice a week. In Fallout New Vegas, how long does it take for stores to restock -- particularly on caps? It feels like it's been at least a week since I woke up in Goodsprings, and the Goodsprings stores aren't restocking on the cap front. (Nor on equipment -- I'd settle for decent stuff to trade, to whittle down my inventory.)

How long must I wait?

Comment: Well, I can't speak to Cap respawns, but from the start of a fresh save, I saw Chet in Goodsprings refresh *his inventory* (I didn't pay attention to cap values) to new Merchandise within 36 hours.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Vendors restock twice per week on Sunday and Wednesday. 72 and 96 hours respectively.

You might also need to be outside of the area the vendor is in.

Comment: You also must leave the area as in fast travel away

Comment: Does this also apply to non-merchant NPCs (like caravan players)?

Answer (score 2):

If you sell stuff to a vendor so that the vendor has less caps than normal, **AND** buy something (doesn't matter what, a pencil should do), save, kill the vendor, and then reload the save, the vendor's caps should reset (not the pencil that you bought, though). However, this will not work if you don't buy anything, at least it didn't for me. I'm not sure how to get the item stock to reset, but I'm almost sure that it's something like what I wrote above. I tested this because just killing the vendor and reloading a save didn't work. It did when I tried buying something too.

Comment: I think exiting the shop may act in the same way as saving and killing the vendor in this answer

Answer (score 1):

The vendors restock every 72-hours game-time.

Comment: Are we sure this is constant across all stores/vendors? I've +1ed the answer, but I swear some of the stores and wasteland merchants are taking longer -- especially roving merchants ...

Answer (score 0):

its 72hours in NV if you have all the DLC's and found that sleeping bag or have that camping perk whatever its called use the sleeping bag its called "Roughin' It! Bedroll Kit" and use to sleep for 72 hours. it works for me

Comment: The DLC and bedroll don't really have anything to do with it.

Comment: And, iirc you need to be outside of the area. Welcome to the site Belial! Gathering you first dozen rep to be able to comment (which this answer would have been better as) can be hard. Suggesting edits. Or answering questions that are unanswered. Or ask a smart question about that one thing in that one game that has been bothering you for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after you buy from the vendor save, then attack and or kill them, reload your game and they should have replenished there inventory